# Changing NTP distributed time locally

Tags: time, utc, ntp

I need a solution for a local NTP time server to distribute time adjusted to our local time zone.

The issue is the manufacturer of a product we use have updated their hardware to a newer model and have removed the option to select the time zone in the NTP server settings. As well as removing the RTC from the units so if we set the time manually and the unit is power cycled we lose the time that was set. So we currently have 30 units running a firmware that allows TZ adjusted timing and 20 units that do not. And the manufacturers data logger logs the time from the units instead of the local machines time.

This is posing an issue as we use the data for incident investigation and the times in the data logger need to be in local time not UTC.

So is there an option for a local hosted NTP server that can receive NTP time from 0.au.pool.org and then redistribute on the local network time zone adjusted time. Then I can point the units NTP server to a local address.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for recommending tools to you. We're for solving programming problems, so that means if you were to code up your own solution and run into an issue that you can't get past while doing so, you could show us your code and clearly explain what's wrong with it. But we're not code to write the code from scratch, nor serve as a software recommendation service.

Comment: @Andrew Specifically in the last paragraph, first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

NTP does not care or know anything about timezones.  The timezone is set by the local device.

There is NOT an option on ANY NTP server to redistribute time zone adjusted time since the NTP packet does not have bits for this (plus timezones are set by arbitrary government edicts, so as such were never considered in the NTP protocol design).  So. IF there is such a tool then it would be effectively breaking NTP.  You could of course do/hack this (basically, distribute the wrong time), but it is NOT how this objective (use time zones in geographically separated systems) is met in any of the probably millions of NTP systems I managed for decades (using UTC makes comparing log files easier in my opinion, but a few folks strongly prefer their more familiar local time--it's much harder for servers to keep up with decrees then client systems, esp. in global networks).  *Rather, as I've said, the time zone is set by the local client systems--NEVER by NTP server(s).*

Comment: @Rob Congratulations on miss-understanding the basics of the NTP protocol, which I thought was obvious by your question